# Python: Joining two dataframes on a primary key

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames A and B. I want to replace the rows in A with rows in B where a specific column is equal to each other.

```
A:
      1           2           3
0   asd     0.304012       0.358484
1   fdsa    -0.198157      0.616415
2   gfd    -0.054764       0.389018
3   ff         NaN         1.164172

B:
      1           2           3
0   asd     10.4012       1.458484
1   fdsa    100.198157      2.015
```

I want the following result:

```
      1           2           3
0   asd     10.4012        1.458484   (row merged from B on column 1)
1   fdsa    100.198157     2.015      (row merged from B on column 1)
2   gfd    -0.054764       0.389018
3   ff         NaN         1.164172
```

Comment: Can you post code and data, what you are asking is very generic but your data schema may have some specific requirements, also show the desired output

Comment: I have made an example now. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update): this will overwrite the lhs df with the contents of the rhs df where there is a match in your case replace `df` and `df1` with `A` and `B` respectively:

```
In [13]:

df.update(df1)
df
Out[13]:
      1           2         3
0   asd   10.401200  1.458484
1  fdsa  100.198157  2.015000
2   gfd   -0.054764  0.389018
3    ff         NaN  1.164172
```